# Is there any way with apache httpclient to set credentials based of a URI

Tags: java, resteasy, apache-httpclient-4.x

Currently I have some uris that I call using resteasy that That looks something like this:

```
http://host.com/api/project1/getsomestuff
```

and

```
http://host.com/api/project2/getsomestuff
```

Both use digest authentication but require a different username and password for authentication.  Currently in code I have to handle this by creating a different client instance for each project like this:

```
DefaultHttpClient project1Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
Credentials project1Credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user1", "password1");
project1Client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, project1Credentials);
ClientExecutor executor1 = new ApacheHttpClient4Executor(project1Client);
MyService project1Proxy = ProxyFactory.create(MyService.class, executor1);
project1Proxy.getSomeStuff("project1");

DefaultHttpClient project2Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
Credentials project2Credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user2", "password2");
project2Client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, project1Credentials);
ClientExecutor executor2 = new ApacheHttpClient4Executor(project1Client);
MyService project2Proxy = ProxyFactory.create(MyService.class, executor2);
project2Proxy.getSomeStuff("project2");
```

I have looked through AuthScope and CredentialsProvider and I just can't see any way how this would be possible.  Does anybody know of any way to use both sets of credentials using the same client or am I stuck using multiple clients?

Also, please note that I do not control the server side of this rest call and both calls use the same realm so I am unable to set the different credentials per realm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those applications have a different security contexts they are also likely to have different authentication realms (or at least they are expected to). One can explicitly set the realm attribute on the AuthScope object to explicitly match it to a specific authentication context with the given realm name.

Comment: Unfortunately in this case the realm from the server is the same for both uris and I don't control the server side of the interaction.

Comment: I see. Actually there is nothing wrong with using multiple clients in such a case. You might want to make them share one connection pool, though. This should be as resource efficient as using one HttpClient instance.

Comment: I was hoping to do a bit cleaner implementation but couldn't find another option so I went with your suggestion of multiple client instances sharing resources such as the connection pool.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are out of luck. Looking through the docs you cannot create an Authscope which sends a different password to different paths on the same host and port.

Comment: Not necessarily. That is what authentication realms are for.